# Microsoft Teams developer platform, add push notification ? (blocking if it is possible)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am developing a Microsoft Teams custom tab app, and i want that if a event occurs in the server, notify to the teams client, and if the client is in other Teams tab, the client show a prompt (with sound?) to see the event or to link to my custom tab.

That is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to do this is to include a bot as part of your app, and then the bot can send a message to the user as needed. The user will receive a normal Teams message notification toast. This would use something called [Proactive Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging), to send a message on a trigger.